# Windows won't boot

Tags: windows, boot

I accidentally deleted my boot record with this program called EASYBCD. I now cannot boot into windows. I used my windows 10 recovery drive to refresh my PC and delete all files. After a while, I get a message saying it failed to recover this PC. I tried the bootrec/fixmbr but it said I only had windows on the `E:` drive. I chose that and it said could not find the media specified. If I take my flash drive out and boot, it says no operating systems installed. I am stuck and don't know what to do.

EDIT: For people with this problem, I made a windows installation usb, then during setup converted disk to GPT (video on how to do this [Here](https://youtu.be/pb6tECZP6WE)). I then installed as normal.

Comment: Ouch.  From what you're saying, and from my knowledge of the programs, it sounds like EasyBCD made Windows inaccessible.  Still there, but not visible; easily fixed with proper EasyBCD usage.  But then deleting all files made recoverability much more difficult.  And converting to GPT and re-installing removed the ability to undelete.  Hopefully you had good backups.  In the future, slow down on such destructive actions that make reversal more challenging; it's possible that a fix could've restored your old system in 10 minutes w/ proper knowledge/care/expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I just did exactly the same thing today. I was on the verge of reinstalling Windows 10, when I finally found something to do that worked.

On the Toshiba I have, there is a system recovery mode, which one can get to by powering up while holding the 0 key. [If you have a Toshiba, see link here.](https://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=2737864) This gets to a mode with a few options, including wiping the disk and reinstalling. It had a "fix problems" option that didn't work for my case. However it also had a Command Prompt option. I imagine that non-Toshiba users, even if they have no such recovery mode, could probably get a Windows 10 command prompt to run from USB media.

Once at a command prompt, I was able to use the bootrec.exe program, specifically:

```
bootrec.exe  /RebuildBcd
```

Which found my Windows 10 partition and rebuilt the BCD, enabling me to restart and recover my Windows 10 without losing anything but the time/angst of the last hour or two. I owe that knowledge the [useful article here](http://www.7tutorials.com/command-prompt-fix-issues-your-boot-records), which may have other helpful bits for others in similar/related situations.

(Oh, and apparently when one registers on the EasyBCD site, one can get a version later than 2.2, and apparently 2.2 doesn't support Windows 10, but versions 2.3+ do... though I'm not sure I want to try messing with EasyBCD again...)